# How to specify target machine type THUMB for object files in the Visual Studio 2008 compiler

Tags: visual-studio, windows-ce

I'm developing a dll project for Windows CE 6.0 with Visual Studio. For that I'm trying to compile a third-party library that links to the corelib.dll of a vendor-specific platform SDK. During the linking stage, I get a LNK1112 error that says, that the module machine type X86 conflicts with the target machine type THUMB. With dumpbin I found out that indeed the machine type of the corelib.dll is THUMB and the machine type of the object files are X86. How do I tell the vc compiler to generate object files with machine type THUMB?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio will generate executable files for the machine type(s) supported by your SDK. If the SDK is x86 only you'll need to get an ARM enabled SDK to build your code (you can try with those http://developer.toradex.com/frequent-downloads#Windows_CE_SDK but I can't grant that they provide all the features included in the OS image running on your target device, the best option would be getting one from the device manufacturer), if the SDK has multiple architecures support you should be able to select an ARM-based configuration when you build your project.

Comment: I'm invoking cl from the command line. What exactly is it that defines the architecture of the output? I can't find any compiler flag. Or is it the compiler itself? I have an SDK from the device manufacturer and I just noticed, there is also an cl.exe. Should I use that?

Comment: Yes, there are different versions of the compiler. In the VC\CE subfolder of your visual studio setup you can find multiple folders for the different architectures. But why do you need to launch just the compiler from the command-line and you don't use the IDE or the command-line build for the whole project (in this way the right compiler will be invoked, taking this information from the SDK selected for that specific configuration).

Comment: I was trying to abstract away the details, but since you are asking: I was actually trying to compile Boost.Test for Windows CE 6. The Boost build system invokes the command line compiler. During build there were linker errors as described above. After inspecting the object files I observed that they had the wrong machine type. After fiddling around a litte bit more, the object files have machine type ARM and everything works fine now. I'm not entirely sure what made it work, though.

Comment: Ok, but the fact that you're building from command line without using the standard VS build system isn't exactly what I would call "a detail" :) Since the compiler name is the same maybea change in the PATH env var did the trick.